# bulge effects in java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I was researching bulge effect and I referenced this link below:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266250/explanation-of-this-image-warping-bulge-filter-algorithm
the examples image are all nxn type, what if the image is mxn.
i tried to code but it always throws exception: row out of bounds.
my code as follows:

```
public static Picture positionalTransform(Picture picture) {
        int w = picture.width();
        int h = picture.height();
        
        double X = 0;
        double Y = 0;
        
        Picture newPic = new Picture(w,h);
        
        for(int x=0; x<w; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<h; y++){
                X = x - x/2;
                Y = y - y/2;
                double r = Math.hypot(X, Y);
                double angle = Math.atan2(X, Y);
                double rn = Math.pow(r, 2.5)/0.5;
                
                X = (int) (rn * Math.sin(angle) + x/2);
                Y = (int) (rn * Math.cos(angle) + y/2);
                
                newPic.setColor((int)X, (int)Y, picture.getColor(x, y));                                    
            }
        }      
        picture = newPic;
        return picture;
    }
```

Comment: Should be simple adding a test to check whether `X` and `Y` is within bounds (`X < w` and `Y < h`)?

Comment: i tried, but it doesn't work. the resulting picture did not bulge